# Using find | xargs to redirect to output files incorporating the substituted value

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a file to a apache private temp folder on startup of a vagrant VM. The path looks something like this:

```
/tmp/systemd-private-c6d69c26cea64df2ab2980b337e60b79-apache2.service-b0KNWB/tmp
```

I found a way to execute commands reliably on this variable path by doing this:

```
find /tmp/ | grep -P "apache" | head -n 1 | xargs -I% touch %/tmp/aaa.txt
```

Which works fine. If I am trying to write to this file though by executing

```
find /tmp/ | grep -P "apache" | head -n 1 | xargs -I% echo "qweqwe" > %/tmp/aaa.txt
```

I only get `-bash: %/tmp/aaa.txt: Not a directory`.

There must be something wrong with using `echo` with `xargs`, but I'm really stuck here.

Comment: The problem is that redirections are performed *by the shell* _before_ the shell starts `xargs` at all.

Comment: ...so it's not a problem with `echo`, but a problem with `>`. `>` isn't an argument to `echo`, it's a piece of shell syntax that the shell will honor the same way no matter what command is being run.

Comment: That said, this seems like overkill altogether. `for d in /tmp/systemd-private-*apache*/; do [ -d "$d" ] || continue; echo "qweqwe" >"$f/tmp/aaa.txt"; done`, and you don't need `find`, `grep`, `head` _or_ `xargs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider something more like:

```
find /tmp \
  -iname '*apache*' \
  -type d \
  -exec sh -c 'for arg do echo "qweqwe" >"$arg/tmp/aaa.txt"; done' _ {} \;
  -quit  # stop after the first one
```

That way you're putting the redirection inside the code passed to a shell to be run, so it's able to be performed. (If you want to efficiently loop over multiple arguments, just take out the `-quit` and change `_ {} \;` to `_ {} +`).

Moreover, this avoids security problems by passing your filenames as *data* out-of-band from code. A naive solution to make a redirection to might use `xargs -I% sh -c '... >%/tmp/aaa.txt'`, but that's dangerous (like any other place where one substitutes literal data into code): Someone who can create a filename like `/tmp/$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'/evil/apache/` could then cause you to delete your home directory when you run this code.

Comment: Cheers, your suggestion in your other comment is working fine: `for d in /tmp/systemd-private-*apache*/; do [ -d "$d" ] || continue; echo "qweqwe" >"$d/tmp/aaa.txt"; done`. I knew my approach was probably overkill.